# How to display bootstrap-datepicker in custom container?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to display bootstrap-datepicker in container after user clicks on a custom control (div). Input fields are hidden.
Here's what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/bczjxv8x/1/

I initialize datepicker to use custom container:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    container: '.container'
});
```

And then on click I open datepicker:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
});
```

Problem is that datepicker pops up with left and top properties calculated and is not in right place. I need that datepicker to pop up right over container. If I use '.containter' to initialize datepicker, it starts in inline mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using bootstrap 4
You have to create a container like this:

```
    <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="12-02-2012">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Important is to use "**input-group**" class
have a look at the [docu](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html)

I also had to put `'.input-group'` to the container option

I tried it with other classes and ids but it didn't work. This was the only working solution

Also have a look to this [guide](https://formden.com/blog/date-picker)